# keep decimal places when cast a float to a string in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm writing an ATM program for school.  I've been doing a lot of research trying to figure out why when my numbers are like 100.00 they become 100.0 when cast as strings.  I've tried many different things but always get errors.

```
import sys

#account balance
acct_bal = float(500.25)
deposit_amount = float(0.00)
balance = float(0.00)
withdrawal_amount = float(0.00)

#<--------functions go here-------------------->
#printbalance function, choice B
def account_balance(acct_bal):
    print("Your current balance:")
    print(acct_bal)

#deposit function, choice D
def deposit(deposit_amount, balance):
    print("Deposit was $" + str(float(deposit_amount)) + ", current balance is $" + str(float(balance)))
    #print("Deposit was $" + "{:,.2f}".format(deposit_amount) + ", current balance is $" + "{:,.2f}".format(balance))
    #This one causes an error
    #Traceback (most recent call last):
    #File "G:/SNHU/1 - CURRENT/IT-140 Introduction to Scripting Python (10-30-17 to 12-24-17)/Module 5/ATM", line 29, in <module>
    #deposit(deposit_amount, balance)
    #File "G:/SNHU/1 - CURRENT/IT-140 Introduction to Scripting Python (10-30-17 to 12-24-17)/Module 5/ATM", line 17, in deposit
    #print("Deposit was $" + "{:,.2f}".format(deposit_amount) + ", current balance is $" + "{:,.2f}".format(balance))
    #ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'

#withdraw function, choice W
def withdrawal(withdrawal_amount, balance):
    print("Withdrawal amount was $" + str(float(withdrawal_amount)) + ", current balance is $" + str(float(balance)))

#User Input goes here, use if/else conditional statement to call function based on user input
userchoice = input("What would you like to do?\n")

if (userchoice == "D"):
    deposit_amount = input("How much would you like to deposit today?\n")
    balance = acct_bal + float(deposit_amount)
    deposit(deposit_amount, balance)
elif (userchoice == "B"):
    account_balance(acct_bal)
else:
    withdrawal_amount = input("How much would you like to withdraw?\n")
    balance = acct_bal - float(withdrawal_amount)
    withdrawal(withdrawal_amount, balance)
```

This is the output I get:

```
What would you like to do?
W
How much would you like to withdraw?
100
Withdrawal amount was $100.0, current balance is $400.25
```

Should be >

```
Withdrawal amount was $100.00, current balance is $400.25
```

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limiting floats to two decimal points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points)

Comment: Use those commented out lines with `{:,.2f}.format(...)`.

Comment: And pass a number, not a string, to the `deposit` function. (You need to convert the result of `input` to a number.)

Comment: Or, `print("Deposit was $%.2f, current balance is $%.2f") % (deposit_amount, balance))`.

Comment: I tried the {:,.2f}".format(deposit_amount) which gave the errors listed under the def deposit() function.

Comment: dkato, I tried yours and get a different error:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
Deposit was $%.2f, current balance is $%.2f
  File "G:/SNHU/1 - CURRENT/IT-140 Introduction to Scripting Python (10-30-17 to 12-24-17)/Module 5/ATM", line 42, in <module>
    deposit(deposit_amount, balance)
  File "G:/SNHU/1 - CURRENT/IT-140 Introduction to Scripting Python (10-30-17 to 12-24-17)/Module 5/ATM", line 20, in deposit
    print("Deposit was $%.2f, current balance is $%.2f") % (deposit_amount, balance)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'tuple'

Comment: Try `print("Deposit was $%.2f, current balance is $%.2f" % (deposit_amount, balance))`

Comment: The easiest way would be to use `format` function of `str`

Answer (score 2):

if you are using python 3.x then there is a simple way to go about it.

```
value = 100.000

#the .2f specifys the number of trailing values after the decimal you want
final = "{:.2f}".format(value)

print(final)
#output:100.00
#NOTE: it will be in string
#if you want more formatting options you can check the python docs
```

Comment: I get these errors: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/SNHU/1 - CURRENT/IT-140 Introduction to Scripting Python (10-30-17 to 12-24-17)/Module 5/ATM", line 44, in <module>
    deposit(deposit_amount, balance)
  File "G:/SNHU/1 - CURRENT/IT-140 Introduction to Scripting Python (10-30-17 to 12-24-17)/Module 5/ATM", line 20, in deposit
    deposit_amount = "{:,.2f}".format(deposit_amount)
ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'

Comment: why is there a comma there "{:','.2f}"